# Magento2 Admin, https loop

Tags: magento2, server-setup, apache2

I would like my Magento 2 shop to be accessible only via HTTPS. So I added this line to the Apache2 config file:

```
Redirect / https://www.domain.com/
```

The issue is that now the backend can't be accessed. Here is the error message:

```
domain.com redirected you too many times.
```

Comment: are you trying  on local host ?

Comment: No its on the production server

Comment: Check web/secure/use_in_adminhtml and web/secure/use_in_frontend settings in core_config_data, they both should be set to 1

Comment: delete cookies for domain, clear all cache

Comment: Thx @RahulSingh that worked. You can post the answer so I mark it as solution

Comment: Welcome, happy to help u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these Steps:

1) Check `web/secure/use_in_adminhtml` and `web/secure/use_in_frontend` settings in `core_config_data,` they both should be set to **1**

2) Delete cookies for domain

3) Clear all Cache